# Proving $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) =1$ using calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, proof-verification

Ok so the book in which I found this doesn't say mention the trigonometric functions by name but the question is:

Let $s(x)$ and $c(x)$ be functions satisfying $s'(x)=c(x)$ and $c'(x)= -s(x)$ for all $x$. If $s(0)=0$ and $c(0)=1$, prove that $s^2(x) + c^2(x) =1$.

I tried using integrals and derivatives but could only show that the derivative of  $s'(x)+c'(x)$ is $s(x) + c(x)$ but I think that was completely wrong way to think about it. I didn't read too well up on the mean value theorem and Rolle's theorem and perhaps the proof uses those theorems. Anyway could any one show me proof of this? Thanks.

Comment: What's the derivative of $s^2+c^2$?

Comment: yes I do. Im sorry I just fixed it

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich wouldn't that be 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \sin^2 x+\cos^2 x-1\;,$ Then $f'(x) = 2\sin x\cdot \cos x+2\cos x\cdot(-\sin x)+0 = 0$

So We get $f'(x) = 0\Rightarrow f(x) = \mathcal{C}$

Now $\displaystyle f\left(0\right) = \sin^2 0+\cos^2 0 -1 =0$

So Put $x=0$ in $f(x) = \mathcal{C}\;,$ We get $f(0)=\mathcal{C}$

So we get $\mathcal{C} = 0$

So We get $f(x)=\mathcal{C} = 0\Rightarrow f(x) = 0\Rightarrow \sin^2 x+\cos^2 x= 1$

Answer (score 4):

Take the derivative of $s^2+c^2$ and you'll see it's zero and is therefore a constant function. With the initial conditions, it must be one.

Answer (score 1):

You need the chain rule on the function $f(x)=s(x)^2+c(x)^2.$ Then $f'(x)=2s(x)s'(x)+2c(x)c'(x),$ which is zero when you sub in your conditions. So this $f(x)$ is a constant, and now plug in say $x=0.$